# Can someone tell me the name of this flower please

Tags: identification

[image][image]

Can someone tell me the name of this flower please.

Comment: If no one else identifies this from your picture, can you please add more info - like is it a tree, a shrub, or a lowgrowing plant, and a pic showing more foliage and growth habit/overall appearance.

Comment: Welcome to the site Thomas. What a pretty flower! In addition to the information @Bamboo asked for, would you please let us know where you live? It can be especially helpful in identifying regional plants.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo and Sue. I have upload another picture. It's a shrub or a vine. From Sydney Australia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for the extra pic, but it didn't help much - the fact its a shrub and you're in Oz did though - its Cestrum newellii. Link below shows a pic, although yours is in much better nick! The one in this pic is just starting to go over...

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/378724649883673020/